# Why Map is faster than Objects in JS?

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary, javascript-objects

I've been looking fot a decent answer for days. Some people just say *"map is better when dinamically removing/adding (key, value)"* or *"you should use map when all keys are the same datatype and all values are all the same datatype"*. **But why???**

Comment: Dynamic keys on objects have problems due to possible shadowing or invoking of `Object.prototype` methods. I think Maps are also more efficient in such situations due to the hidden classes of objects in V8. I have no idea about the second quote in your question, never heard that before, it looks suspect to me

Comment: But considering let a = Object.create(null); there's NO prototype, but map still much faster.. (I have a script whereas i'm testing which is faster).
And what you do mean by "hidden classes of objects", how could this increase performance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323217/how-are-hidden-classes-in-the-v8-engine-implemented https://engineering.linecorp.com/en/blog/v8-hidden-class/ etc - google shows a lot of links

Comment: I didn't know about the term, thanks.
But hidden classes are implemented for both Map and Object right? then it still not making sense to me